# Global Variable Not Working in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, global-variables, nsuserdefaults, anyobject

I have created a small tabbed view program that uses tabs to switch between two views. There is one global variable called list that is an array containing information that both views need to access and change. However, when I try to use NSUserDefaults to save the array for future use in the app after it is closed, I got an error saying: "Cannot convert value of type 'Array<_>' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'". Here is my code for my second view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var reminder: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {

}
@IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {
    if reminder.text == "" {
        label.text = "Please type a reminder!"
    } else {
        list.append(reminder.text!)
        reminder.text = ""
        label.text = "Add A Reminder"
    }

    // The below line is giving the error!!!!!

    // Specifically the fact that I am using the variable "list"

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(list, forKey: "reminders")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

I'm guessing that this has something to do with the fact that the list variable is a global variable, but I would appreciate some help with fully diagnosing this problem!

Edit:

I have solved this problem by declaring the global variable list like this:

var list:[String] = String

Instead of:

var list:Array = []

Comment: Where is `list` defined (as it isn't shown in the code)? I know it's global but where in general. Also have you tried `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(list as? AnyObject, forKey: "reminders") `

Comment: It is defined in FirstViewController.swift, while the code that I put there is from SecondViewController.swift

Comment: Where is your list declaration? If you're saving strings in that array, make it array of strings: var list: [String]?

Comment: I am saving strings in the array, but I can't seem to store it as permanent data.

Comment: Oh my god it worked, what you said about making it an [String], I said:

Comment: var list:[String] instead of var list:Array

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll post the solution in the question!